# Run script in the host when starting virtual machine with virt-manager

Tags: scripting, mount, virtual-machine, automounting, libvirt

This is related to my question on Ask Ubuntu: [Add physical partition to QEMU/KVM virtual machine in virt-manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/927574/495331) (see "Updates" near the end, if needed).

Is there a nice way to run any arbitrary script on the host every time a VM is started from virt-manager?

The reason is that I want to automagically unmount the ESP partition `/dev/sda1` (mounted in the host as `/boot/efi`), and remount it when the VM is powered off.

[update] The script I was using [can be found here](https://gitlab.com/ranolfi/rvirtesp/blob/master/usr/local/sbin/rvirtesp).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [libvirt: Hooks for specific system management](https://libvirt.org/hooks.html):

> **Script names**
>
> At present, there are five hook scripts that can be called:
>
> - `/etc/libvirt/hooks/daemon`
>   Executed when the libvirt daemon is started, stopped, or reloads its configuration
> - `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu`
>   Executed when a QEMU guest is started, stopped, or migrated
>
> (...)
>
> **Script arguments**
>
> The hook scripts are called with specific command line arguments,
> depending upon the script, and the operation being performed.
>
> (...)
>
> The command line arguments take this approach:
>
> 1. The first argument is the name of the **object** involved in the operation, or '-' if there is none.
>    For example, the name of a guest being started.
> 2. The second argument is the name of the **operation** being performed.
>    For example, "start" if a guest is being started.
>
> (...)
>
> **/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu**
>
> - Before a QEMU guest is started, the qemu hook script is called in three locations; if any location fails, the guest is not started. The
>   first location, since 0.9.0, is before libvirt performs any resource
>   labeling, and the hook can allocate resources not managed by libvirt
>   such as DRBD or missing bridges. This is called as:
>   `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu guest_name prepare begin -`
>
>   The second location, available Since 0.8.0, occurs after libvirt has finished labeling all resources, but has not yet started the
>   guest, called as:
>   `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu guest_name start begin -`
>
>   The third location, 0.9.13, occurs after the QEMU process has successfully started up:
>   `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu guest_name started begin -`
>
> (...)

---

### So, in practice, this:

**/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu** (without extension)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "<domain_name>" ]] && [[ $2 == "start" || $2 == "stopped" ]]
then
  if [[ $2 == "start" ]]
  then
    # unmount logic here
  else
    # mount logic here
  fi
fi
```

Of course, edit `<domain name>`, implement the mount/unmount logic, and then restart `libvirtd.service`.

Also don't forget to: `chmod +x /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu`

I'm making my full solution available at https://gitlab.com/ranolfi/rvirtesp.

An *addendum*: for this particular use case,
you may find it useful to set up your `fstab` file with the option `noauto`
and maybe also `x-systemd.automount`
and `x-systemd.device-timeout=<seconds>`. 
See [fstab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) and [systemd.automount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but I think the scripts are a bit complicated.
This line is wrong:
`if [[ $1 == "rwin10" ]] && [[ $2 == "start" ]] || [[ $2 == "stopped" ]]`
It's executed on **any** VM stop, the correct line is `if [[ $1 == "rwin10" && ( $2 == "start" || $2 == "stopped" ) ]]`

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter variant of your scripts. Put this in `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu`:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1:$2 in
win11:start)
    umount /boot/efi
    ;;
win11:stopped)
    mount /boot/efi
    ;;
esac
```

and make it executable. Here `win11` is the guest name.

PS: It's actually a comment. I put it as an answer because of formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope to revisit this soon, with your improvements and due credit.

Comment: You are welcome